# Пустой экран при переключении вида товаров

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

такая проблема, когда выбираю модель телефона из фильтра в каталоге и переключаю вид с сетки на список, то появляется пустой экран.
С чем может это быть связанно? Установлен Woocommerce, Тема the 7, [вот сайт](http://mixapple.ru)

Comment: У меня всё работает. Почистите кеши.

Comment: Вы видимо сделали все в другой последовательности.
Перейдите на главную сайта, далее в каталоге выпадет подменю и кликайте apple, выбирайте любую модель из фильтра и в списке товаров переключаете вид на список и видите пустой экран. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: У вас какая-то проблема с редиректами. Вы создали страницу /apple, всё из-за этого. Если оставаться в каталоге, работает нормально.

Comment: И как можно решить данную проблему не подскажете?

Comment: Так снаружи глядя - нет идей. Надо разбираться, как и что у вас сделано.

Comment: Созданы категории товаров в Woocommerce

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD